# Tool to show history and easily uninstall recently-installed deb packages

Tags: linux, package-manager, uninstall

I know it is possible to manually inspect `/var/log/dpkg.log` or `/var/log/apt/history.log`, but that is not what I call "easy to use".

So is there a tool that will parse those log files, and show me the packages that have been installed, sorted by date, so I can mark the ones I wish to uninstall, press a button, and they get uninstalled?

I need something that's not Ubuntu-specific, because I'm on Debian 7.4, and it needs to catch all packages - even packages installed through `dpkg -i`.

So far, I know of these programs that have somethings similar, but not quite what I need:

- **Synaptic** has <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>History</kbd>, but it shows only packages installed through Synaptic.
- **Ubuntu Software Center** had something like that, but it is Ubuntu-only. Not sure if it catches things installed outside of Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such tool in Debian, neither in Debian 7 nor in the upcoming Debian 8.

The only tool which goes into that direction is `which-pkg-broke` from the `debian-goodies` package. You pass one package as parameter and it recursively lists all dependencies, sorted by the last installation/upgrade date. Not sure if that helps you at least a bit.